# Whitening data for Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning

I have a dataset in which there is high correlation between the (500+) columns. From what I understand (and correct me if I am wrong), one of the reasons that you do normalising with zero mean and a std dev of one is so that it is easier for a optimizer with a given learning rate to deal with across many problems, rather than adopt the learning rate to the scale of X.

Similarly is there a reason as to why I should 'whiten' my dataset. It seems to be a common step in image processing. Would it make it easier on the optimizer somehow if the columns were independent?

I understand that classically people used to decorrelate the matrices so that the weights became more statistically significant, and also to make the matrix inversion more stable. The matrix inversion part atleast seems to be non-existent when it comes to DL since we use variations of Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) these days instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's not something really essential now. Read this [note](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/) from Andrej. Normally we don't use PCA in deep learning architectures. Because we don't need to reduce features since we have deep architectures which can extract hierarchical features. It's always good to zero center data. Which means you need to normalize data in order to reduce variance in the batch. Anyway normally in CNN we use batch normalization layer. This really helps the network to converge without having covariate shift. ALso modern optimization techniques like adam.rmsprop make the data pre-processing part less important.